# implementing a static polymorphic iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement an iterator interface for a templated type hierarchy that uses static polymorphism to avoid overhead associated with solutions that forward to an implementation (unless it can be compiled away).

I've included a short demonstration of the types and interfaces I'm building, and inline comments referencing where I am getting stuck.

The top of the hierarchy shown directly below is a generic `Box<T>`. The `Convert` method may return a new `Box<U>` by applying a function `U Func(Box<T>)` function to each element.

```
template<typename T>
class Box : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Box<T>> {
 public:
  template <typename Func>
  auto Convert(Func f) -> std::shared_ptr<Box<decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))>>;

  // This is what I am trying to achieve using a statically
  // compiled solution (e.g. without the use of a subclass
  // returning an implementation pointer and using pimpl).
  //
  // const_iterator cbegin();
  // const_iterator cend();

  // Uses the sub-class cbegin/cend interface
  std::vector<T> elements() {
    std::vector<T> result;
    std::copy(cbegin(), cend(), std::back_inserter(result);
    return result;
  }
};
```

And here is a `ConvertedBox<T>` that stores a pointer to a Box and a conversion function. Here the iterator is a wrapper around the referenced variable `rdd_` that that applies `func_` each time the iterator is dereferenced.

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename Func>
class ConvertedBox : public Box<T> {
 public:
  ConvertedBox(typename std::shared_ptr<Box<U>> box, Func func) :
    box_(box), func_(func)
  {}

  // Return iterator wrapper around box_->cbegin()
  //const_iterator cbegin()
  //const_iterator cend()

 private:
  std::shared_ptr<Box<U>> box_;
  Func func_;
};
```

And finally we provide a source box that wraps a concrete vector (other sources are used in practice).

```
template<typename T>
class VectorBox : public Box<T> {
 public:
  ConvertedBox(const std::vector<T>& data) : data_(data)
  {}

  // Return iterator wrapper std::vector<T>::const_iterator
  //const_iterator cbegin() {
  //    return data_.cbegin();
  //}
  //const_iterator cend() { ... }

 private:
  const typename std::vector<T>& data_;
};
```

I've tried all sorts of CRTP tricks involving `std::iterator` and cannot seem to put the pieces together for this. I would like to avoid anything that relies on `boost`, but assume anything in `C++11` in OK.

Note that I am only having problems figuring out this iterator situation (the rest of the parts I've included are just for context).

Comment: Are you trying to write something a là [boost::transform_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html)?

Comment: @TomKnapen the challenge i'm facing is (i think) orthogonal to what `boost::transform_iterator` provides. yes, the `ConvertBox` iterators will apply a function by overloading `operator*`, but the more general problem I'm facing in this post is how to provide a consistent iterator interface across the type hierarchy. Is there more to `boost::transform_iterator` that might assist in addressing this question?

Comment: How do you expect to call the subclass `cbegin()` and `cend()` interface in `Box<T>::elements()` if `cbegin()` and `cend()` are not `virtual`?  And by the way...making `cbegin()` and `cend()` virtual would probably cause bad things to happen since the size of the iterator (as called from the base class) would be unknown.

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel sorry for the confusion. i understand that these interfaces won't be virtual.